# LinearLayout with dividers on pre Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-support-library, android-compatibility

From API level 11 [`setDividerDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setShowDividers%28int%29) and [`setShowDividers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setDividerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) was introduced on [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html), enabling the linear layout to show dividers between child elements. I would really like to use this feature, but I am also targeting devices before Honeycomb (API level < 11).

One way to fix this is to extend LinearLayout and add the divider manually. This is a prototype:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DividerLinearLayout extends LinearLayout
{
    public DividerLinearLayout(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public DividerLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DividerLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child)
    {
        if(super.getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            super.addView(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.divider, null));
        }
        super.addView(child);
    }
}
```

However, using such an implementation will change the behavior of any clients iterating over the children. Some views will be the ones inserted by the client himself, some will be inserted by the `DividerLinearLayout`. Problems will also happen if the user is inserting views at specified indexes. One could implement a conversion of indexes, but this could lead to nasty errors if done wrong. Also, I think a lot more of the methods needs to be overridden.

Is there any better way of solving the problem? Has someone already developed a freely usable `DividerLinearLayout` equivalent? It does not seem to exist in the compatibility libraries for Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the ActionBarSherlock library already implemented this to provide backwards compatible ActionBar tabs. You might want to include that library first and give it a whirl before rolling your own.

This is [the code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsLinearLayout.java) for the specific class (com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout).

Comment: I am already using ActionBarSherlock, so `IcsLinearLayout` was an easy drop-in replacement. It works like a charm - thank you for pointing at it.

Comment: seems like it has errors when it's used in xml. also, the link you've provided doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The IcsLinearLayout is internal and since ActionBarSherlock won't be updated anymore, it's recommended to use the one of Google's, called "LinearLayoutICS".

read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547897/how-to-add-dividers-to-linearlayoutics/) of how to use it.