# How to add dividers to LinearLayoutICS?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-linearlayout, android-support-library, divider

### Background

I'm trying to switch my  [**alternative "App Manager" app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) from [**ActionBarSherlock library**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to the [**support library**](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) Google has created, since it gets more updates (ActionBarSherlock is no longer being developed, link [**here**](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/) ) and I think it should cover a lot of functionality.

### The problem

All went well (or so it seems), except for a class named ICSLinearLayout on ActionBarSherlock I've used to show dividers on, that is now called LinearLayoutICS .

It just doesn't show the dividers:

[image]

Note: before you ask "why don't you just use a GridView?", [**here's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203951/how-to-handle-gridview-with-cell-of-different-heights) the reason, and also [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431097/pinnedheader-google-plus-gridview), in case I'd ever want to add headers.

### The code

The code is about the same as I've used for ActionBarSherlock:

```
rowLayout=new LinearLayoutICS(_context,null);
rowLayout.setMeasureWithLargestChildEnabled(true);
rowLayout.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
rowLayout.setDividerDrawable(_context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_divider_holo_dark));
rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
... // add views, layout params, etc...
```

### The question

How can I use this class in order to support showing dividers on all supported OS versions of the support library?

What is wrong with the code I've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems [**setShowDividers**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setShowDividers%28int%29) and [**setDividerDrawable**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setDividerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) cannot be used because LinearLayoutICS doesn't have them .

Not only that, but Lint didn't warn me about it being used.

So, what I ended up with is copying LinearLayoutICS code (from [**here**](https://cells-source.cs.columbia.edu/plugins/gitiles/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-4.3_r1.1/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/LinearLayoutICS.java), hope it's the latest version) and some of the original LinearLayout code, to make something that does work. I hope it doesn't have any bugs.

Long live open source ... :)

Sadly [**setMeasureWithLargestChildEnabled**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setMeasureWithLargestChildEnabled%28boolean%29) isn't available for old APIs, so I think the ActionBarSherlock way is still better in case that's something you wish to use.

EDIT: the **setMeasureWithLargestChildEnabled** method doesn't work on ActionBarSherlock.

Here's the code, for those who wish to use. I hope next time the library gets updated, I will remember to check this issue again.

```
public class LinearLayoutICS extends LinearLayout
  {
  private Drawable mDivider;
  private int      mDividerWidth,mDividerHeight;
  private int      mShowDividers;
  private int      mDividerPadding;

  public LinearLayoutICS(final Context context,final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context,attrs);
    // the R is from "android.support.v7.appcompat.R" .
    final TypedArray a=context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.LinearLayoutICS);
    mDivider=a.getDrawable(R.styleable.LinearLayoutICS_divider);
    if(mDivider!=null)
      {
      mDividerWidth=mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth();
      mDividerHeight=mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
      }
    else mDividerHeight=mDividerWidth=0;
    mShowDividers=a.getInt(R.styleable.LinearLayoutICS_showDividers,SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
    mDividerPadding=a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.LinearLayoutICS_dividerPadding,0);
    a.recycle();
    setWillNotDraw(mDivider==null);
    }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
    if(getOrientation()==VERTICAL)
      drawDividersVertical(canvas);
    else drawDividersHorizontal(canvas);
    }

  @Override
  protected void measureChildWithMargins(final View child,final int parentWidthMeasureSpec,final int widthUsed,final int parentHeightMeasureSpec,final int heightUsed)
    {
    if(mDivider!=null)
      {
      final int childIndex=indexOfChild(child);
      final int count=getChildCount();
      final LayoutParams params=(LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
      // To display the dividers in-between the child views, we modify their margins
      // to create space.
      if(getOrientation()==VERTICAL)
        {
        if(hasDividerBeforeChildAt(childIndex))
          params.topMargin=mDividerHeight;
        else if(childIndex==count-1&&hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count))
          params.bottomMargin=mDividerHeight;
        }
      else if(hasDividerBeforeChildAt(childIndex))
        params.leftMargin=mDividerWidth;
      else if(childIndex==count-1&&hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count))
        params.rightMargin=mDividerWidth;
      }
    super.measureChildWithMargins(child,parentWidthMeasureSpec,widthUsed,parentHeightMeasureSpec,heightUsed);
    }

  void drawDividersVertical(final Canvas canvas)
    {
    final int count=getChildCount();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      {
      final View child=getChildAt(i);
      if(child!=null&&child.getVisibility()!=GONE&&hasDividerBeforeChildAt(i))
        {
        final LayoutParams lp=(LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
        drawHorizontalDivider(canvas,child.getTop()-lp.topMargin);
        }
      }
    if(hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count))
      {
      final View child=getChildAt(count-1);
      int bottom=0;
      if(child==null)
        bottom=getHeight()-getPaddingBottom()-mDividerHeight;
      else bottom=child.getBottom();
      drawHorizontalDivider(canvas,bottom);
      }
    }

  void drawDividersHorizontal(final Canvas canvas)
    {
    final int count=getChildCount();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
      {
      final View child=getChildAt(i);
      if(child!=null&&child.getVisibility()!=GONE&&hasDividerBeforeChildAt(i))
        {
        final LayoutParams lp=(LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
        drawVerticalDivider(canvas,child.getLeft()-lp.leftMargin);
        }
      }
    if(hasDividerBeforeChildAt(count))
      {
      final View child=getChildAt(count-1);
      int right=0;
      if(child==null)
        right=getWidth()-getPaddingRight()-mDividerWidth;
      else right=child.getRight();
      drawVerticalDivider(canvas,right);
      }
    }

  void drawHorizontalDivider(final Canvas canvas,final int top)
    {
    mDivider.setBounds(getPaddingLeft()+mDividerPadding,top,getWidth()-getPaddingRight()-mDividerPadding,top+mDividerHeight);
    mDivider.draw(canvas);
    }

  void drawVerticalDivider(final Canvas canvas,final int left)
    {
    mDivider.setBounds(left,getPaddingTop()+mDividerPadding,left+mDividerWidth,getHeight()-getPaddingBottom()-mDividerPadding);
    mDivider.draw(canvas);
    }

  /**
   * Determines where to position dividers between children.
   *
   * @param childIndex Index of child to check for preceding divider
   * @return true if there should be a divider before the child at childIndex
   * @hide Pending API consideration. Currently only used internally by the system.
   */
  protected boolean hasDividerBeforeChildAt(final int childIndex)
    {
    if(childIndex==0)
      return (mShowDividers&SHOW_DIVIDER_BEGINNING)!=0;
    else if(childIndex==getChildCount())
      return (mShowDividers&SHOW_DIVIDER_END)!=0;
    else if((mShowDividers&SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE)!=0)
      {
      boolean hasVisibleViewBefore=false;
      for(int i=childIndex-1;i>=0;i--)
        if(getChildAt(i).getVisibility()!=GONE)
          {
          hasVisibleViewBefore=true;
          break;
          }
      return hasVisibleViewBefore;
      }
    return false;
    }

  @Override
  public int getDividerPadding()
    {
    return mDividerPadding;
    }

  @Override
  public void setDividerPadding(final int dividerPadding)
    {
    mDividerPadding=dividerPadding;
    }

  @Override
  public void setShowDividers(final int showDividers)
    {
    if(mShowDividers!=showDividers)
      requestLayout();
    mShowDividers=showDividers;
    }

  @Override
  public void setDividerDrawable(final Drawable divider)
    {
    if(divider==mDivider)
      return;
    mDivider=divider;
    if(divider!=null)
      {
      mDividerWidth=divider.getIntrinsicWidth();
      mDividerHeight=divider.getIntrinsicHeight();
      }
    else
      {
      mDividerWidth=0;
      mDividerHeight=0;
      }
    setWillNotDraw(divider==null);
    requestLayout();
    }

  @Override
  public Drawable getDividerDrawable()
    {
    return mDivider;
    }
  }
```